# Android: setpadding not working with imageview

Tags: android, imageview, padding

I have two imageviews and I want to create a border like effect whenever a user clicks on them.
I have set the background of both the imageviews to colour. Now, when a user taps on the image, I set some padding on the imageview so that it creates a border like effect.But, unfortunately its not happening.

this is my java code:

```
public void imageClick(View view)
{
switch(view.getId())
{
case (R.id.imageView1):
     image1.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
     image2.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
     break;
case (R.id.imageView2):
     image1.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
     image2.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
     break;
}
}
```

I can't understand why nothing is happening when the image is clicked. I have tried both

```
android:cropToPadding = "true"
```

and

```
android:cropToPadding = "false"
```

but again, no results.

My xml code for the imageViews:

```
<ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageRegion1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="imageClick"
                    android:cropToPadding="false"
                    android:background="#fffff300" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageRegion2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:onClick="imageClick"
                    android:cropToPadding="false"
                    android:background="#fffff300" />
```

I am setting the imageviews dynamically by :

```
image1.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
image2.setImageBitmap(bitmap2);
```

Comment: change  android:layout_height="match_parent" to android:layout_height="wrap_content" it should works perfectly

Comment: ok ill try that. But what if I want "match_parent" instead of wrap_content ?

Comment: its apply the padding for total root view.so its not effected for indivisual

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work!

Comment: check the answer and try the same

Answer (score 0):

As it seems you are most probably using weightSum & layout_weight mechanism to calculate imageview's width equally or rationally.

If I am right here, in this case, when you are setting padding, its not going to make any change in the already inflated view. As you may expect setting padding value will reduce the width & height. But it will not. Because, due to weight calculation it will take the previous width/height values thus will ignore padding.

I hope this will help you to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/row_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageRegion1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#fffff300"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:onClick="imageClick" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageRegion2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#fffff300"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:onClick="imageClick" />
</LinearLayout>
```

i tried with this above.its working fine for me.try again